# XSLT Attribute name needs to be separated

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am working backwards to create an XML based on a client's desired outcome.  I have an attribute in my XSL that I want the end result to look like this

```
<AlternateId idType="ADID">XYZ</AlternateId>
```

I have it incorrectly as

`<xsl:attribute name="idType">ADID<xsl:value-of select="add:XYZ"/></xsl:attribute>`

This, of course, groups ADID and XYZ together.

How do I get them separated and looking like what I want them to look like?

Answer (score 1):

The `value-of` needs to go *outside* the `attribute` as you want it to be element content rather than part of the attribute value.

```
<xsl:element name="AlternateId">
  <xsl:attribute name="idType">ADID</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="add:XYZ"/>
</xsl:element>
```

But if the attribute name is a fixed string you might as well use a literal result element instead:

```
<AlternateId idType="ADID">
  <xsl:value-of select="add:XYZ"/>
</AlternateId>
```

Comment: Wow.  That was so simple.  I can't believe I made that into a more complex issue than it was!  Thanks so much!